# Passing and Recieving Class Instances from outside of Class Functions (not Methods)

Tags: python, oop

One of the many advantages working with Classes is that there is no need to keep updating the variables values returned from the outside functions (functions declared outside Class definition). Here is the example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.name = arg
    def setName(self, arg):
        self.name = arg
    def getName(self):
        return self.name        

def instanceModifier(instObject):
    instObject.setName('Some Value')

myInst=MyClass('My Name')
print myInst.getName()

instanceModifier(myInst)
print myInst.getName()
```

The `instanceModifier()` function modifies the content of the Instance's `self.name` variable. We don't have to make sure we update the Instance variable since there is no need for it. But I am still wondering if that would be a good practice. Should I be returning the modified Instance Object from  `instanceModifier()` function and assigning the returned instance back to the Instance Object like code below. If not then why not? If yes why yes?

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.name = arg
    def setName(self, arg):
        self.name = arg
    def getName(self):
        return self.name        

def instanceModifier(instObject):
    instObject.setName('Some Value')
    return instObject

myInst=MyClass('My Name')
print myInst.getName()

myInst=instanceModifier(myInst)
print myInst.getName()
```

Comment: Aside: Python style prefers `myInst.name` and `myInst.name` over getters and setters in cases like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO it's most Pythonic to just access `myInst.name` directly.

```
myInst=MyClass('My Name')
print myInst.name

myInst.name = 'Some Value'
print myInst.name
```

There's really no need to use setters/getters unless there's some kind of side-effect or lazy lookup going on, and even then, it's best done using [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).

Comment: In past I had renamed, or even changed the type of the Class variable such as from string to list or to dict. If I would access the Class variable directly in "most Pythonic" way I would have to tweak every line where the Class's variable was accessed directly. Working via Class methods assures this tedious job of modifying a code belongs to someone else.

Comment: I agree with the content of this, but isn't the OP asking about whether he should return the instance itself from a mutating function (which would permit chaining, for example)?

Comment: I agree the question is on completely different subject from the answer received.

Comment: @DSM It's a bit of a non-answer, I guess, but that's because I think the premise of the question itself is weak; usually there's no reason for a setter in Python.

Comment: @dano: I may be missing something, but even though he used getters and setters, I don't think the premise has anything to do with them.  I think it's `def f(x): x.a = 9` vs. `def f(x): x.a = 9; return x`.

Comment: `def f(x): x.a = 9` vs. `def f(x): x.a = 9; return x` is exactly what I would like to know when it comes time to Class instances. Should we (or should not) implicitly set the Class variable's to a returned by function() value. Or should we rely on what function() had already done on its-own: set the Class Instance's variable to a new value.